# Why is fuerte unsupported on natty?

Tags: ubuntu-natty, ros-fuerte, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it just per choice of the repository maintainers or are there some deeper incompatibilities between natty and fuerte? i.e. libs that ship with natty, etc.

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32462/why-is-fuerte-unsupported-on-natty?/) by [robbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1903/robbel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1903/robbel/) on 2012-04-24**:
Steven Bellens describes it below. Still hate to think that there's no easy upgrade path for the natty etc folks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html for the logic and reasoning behind it. How I interpret it: as fuerte is released just before the next Ubuntu LTS release, only one previous release of Ubuntu is supported (Oneiric), because of expected major jumps in library versions in the Oneiric version.

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We debated this at length during the Thirdparty Library/Target Platforms SIG:

http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Planning/Thirdparty

We supported Maverick for Electric and it was a *big* waste of time because:

- Most people using non-LTS releases upgrade to the next non-LTS release
- It wasted a lot of developer time providing compatibility fixes
- non-LTS releases by Ubuntu generally have significant bugs that hurt integration
- it requires many more servers for us to build another distribution

Applying the same logic to Fuerte, plus with Precise (new LTS) around the corner, it would be a huge developer effort with little benefit.

You can still build Fuerte from source on Natty; you just don't get binary builds nor Natty-specific patches.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2